# Maven POM Error in Execution Section

Tags: eclipse, maven

This is mostly a minor annoyance. In my Maven pom.xml file, I'm specifying the antrun plugin, so an  section is needed. This works fine, but Eclipse throws up an error message when I nest an  section in it.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution> <!-- Eclipse puts an error here -->
        <!-- snip -->
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

So, the possibilities are that I made a stupid mistake, that I need to configure something in M2E, etc.

Eclipse is 3.6 with M2E plugin.

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to see this error message, but I assume it's classic m2e "plugin execution not covered" issue. Unfortunatelly, you can't do quickly anything but ignore this.

Read [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) for details.